# Forward call until answered

Tags: twilio

I am trying to use twilio twiml bin to configure a method of calling a number x number of times and will only connect me to the caller if I answer and push 1. I never want it to go to my cell phone voicemail though and maybe have something were it says failed to find contact please call again in a few minutes.

The below is as far as I have gotten and everything else I am trying just breaks the progress. Is there some kind of break in the dial that I need to perform as if I do not answer it goes to my voicemail. Thanks for any and all help!

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">Hold on while we connect you to the emergency contact</Say>
    <Dial callerId="+18885551212">
        <Number>+18889991111</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: This does a lot of what I wanted: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme

The problem is I need CallerID set instead of being passed through from the caller as I wan't to set priority on my cell phone to this number. I can't see how to do that and I cannot see a way to add in the part to confirm the call. I want it to basically nag me until I answer or until x times have been tried.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It does look like you do want most of the behaviour of the Twimlet, and you've already seen how to add CallerID to the `<Dial>` tag.

In order to avoid voicemail, you can use the [`timeout` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-timeout) to set a limit for how long to wait before moving on from dialling that number.

To get the message spoken you before answering the call, you need what is called a ["whisper"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper). You need to set a [`url` attribute on the `<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url) to a URL that responds with the TwiML to [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) the message to you and [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) your response.

To loop round and call your number again, you need to set an [`action` attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action), which is the URL that is called when the call is over, whether because it wasn't answered or was completed. You can use that to loop through the call a few times, until a certain threshold, and then cancel calling.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I also had a ticket with twilio on it also but it looks like it was closed as I cannot click on it to see the status. Their response was a bit different but similar but I cannot follow it enough to get a valid twiml bin.

Comment: <Number url="http://www.twimlets.com/whisper?Message=&HumanCheck=1">18885551212</Number>

```

Also, the caller id must either be a verified number or Twilio number.

If you check the twiml below:

http://www.twimlets.com/whisper?Message=&HumanCheck=1

<Response>
<script/>
<Gather numDigits="1">
<Say>
You are receiving a call from . Press any key to accept.
</Say>
</Gather>
<Hangup/>
</Response>

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say in these comments. If you are trying to post code that is working or not working, can you edit your question and provide more details there?

Comment: How do i turn off the "you are receiving a call from number, press 1" intro?
Im using the http://twimlets.com/findme? twimlet. Tried putting in http://twimlets.com/findme?HumanCheck=0&PhoneNumbers...
HumanCheck=0 but it doesn't turn it off.

Comment: @X10D does it say it is a Twilio number? I think that is because you are still using a trial account. To turn off the message you need to upgrade your account.

Comment: It's not a trial acount. It uses TTS to say the number that's being forwarded. And then asks to press 1 to receive the call.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't read your question correctly. The twimlet is built to provide a whisper to the other person. If you just want it to dial many numbers and connect when you pick up, you can create a [TwiML Bin](http://twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) which uses one `<Dial>` with multiple `<Number>`s.